# matching a folder path with regex with forward slash

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have a following regex to match a folder name. What I am trying to get is to match a string with letter, digits, dot, hyphen, underscore and forward slash such that the string doesn't need to start or end with forward stash or dot:

```php
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9.\/_\-])[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,253}[^(.|/|\\)]$/
```

I need to match folder name `foo.com/sdsds`.

But the regular expression is not matching `/`.

Comment: What are the rules you tried to implement in the regex? `[^(.|/|\\)]` is certainly a user error since this does not denote "string should not end with". Moreover, this pattern just does not let your code compile since `/` used in the pattern is not escaped in a `/`-delimited regex in PHP.

Comment: The / has been escaped. The path doesn't need to end  with dot, / or \

Comment: What I am trying to  get is to match a string with letter,digits, dot , hyphen , underscore and forward slash such that the string doesn't need to start or end with forward stash or dot

Comment: Then see https://regex101.com/r/IQVZn8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?![\/.])[\w.\/-]{1,253}$(?<![.\/])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQVZn8/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![\/.])` - no `/` or `.` allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `[\w.\/-]{1,253}` - one to 123 digits, letters, underscores, `.`, `/` or `-` chars
- `$(?<![.\/])` - end of string with no `.` or `/` immediately preceding it.