# Match first folder of the path with protocol and subdomain with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match this path with regex and fail:

`https://subdomain.example.com/path`

There is a [solution for very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70834273), looking like

```
^(?![\/.])[\w.\/-]{1,253}$(?<![.\/])
```

but it doesn't proceed protocol, subdomain and domain, I guess this is the cause, why it doesn't work for me.

What could be the way to adjust this solution for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex, which worked for me, is:

`^(https:\/\/subdomain\.example\.com)\/{1}([a-zA-Z\-]{1,256})$`

It matches `/path` in `https://subdomain.example.com/path` and doesn't match it in `https://subdomain.example.com/prevpath/path`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
.+?://.+?/(.+?)(?:$|/)
```

Example input

```
https://subdomain.example.com/pathA
https://subdomain.example.com/pathA/pathB/
https://subdomain.example.com/pathA/pathB/pathC
```

Output

```
pathA
pathA
pathA
```